# Remove Node child if equals variable

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I am trying to remove a li node if it equals a specific variable.
For instance

- If username == User 1
- And if a node equaled User 1

Then I would like this node to be removed. I haven't been able to set id's for the nodes. This is the code that sets the child's nodes.

```
 $('#typing').append($('<li>').text(username + "is drawing..."));
```

And this is the code that I am using to try and remove the specific node.

```
if ($('<li>'.text == username + " is drawing...")){
           console.log("its the same!");
           $("<li>").remove();
           prev_username = "";
       }
    });
```

In this code it is printing out "its the same" so its just the action of actually removing the node. Any chance anyone could help me out of this I would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement will always result to true as it is testing a jQuery object which, regardless of how it's constructed is truthy.

You can use a selector like contains to find the li's you're looking for.

```js
var username = 'Jefferey John Smith';

$('#typing').append($('<li>').text(username + " is drawing..."));

$('button').click(function(){
    $('li:contains('+ username + ' is drawing...)').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="typing">
    <li>Musa is typing...
</ul>
<button>Clear Jefferey John Smith</button>
```